# formatting round value with 2 decimal in php

Tags: php, formatting, rounding

Have to round the number in php.
I have tried like below,

```
round(12.4569,2);
```

it will return 12.46. its OK.

But,
round(12.4003,2);

the output is 12.4

But need the output  12.40

suggestion please...

Comment: using `number_format`, `sprintf` you can done this action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use number_format :

```
number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this in ur code :

number_format(12.4003,2);

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `sprintf` function:

```
print_r(sprintf("%.2f",12.4003,2));   // 12.40
print_r(sprintf("%.2f",12.4569,2));   // 12.46
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php